# Program to debug memory leaks on armv4 architecture

Tags: c, linux, debugging, arm, valgrind

I have a linux device that has armv4 CPU, and develop C code on it. I would like to debug my code via `valgrind`. However, I get a message saying that valgrind does not support armv4l. I wonder if there would be a way to suppress the error or what could be an alternative debugging package to analyze memory leaks?

Here is how I try to install the `valgrind`

```
ts7500:/home# tar -xjf valgrind-3.8.1.tar.bz2
ts7500:/home# cd valgrind-3.8.1
ts7500:/home/valgrind-3.8.1# ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for ar... /usr/bin/ar
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for gdb... /usr/bin/gdb
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for diff -u... yes
checking for a supported version of gcc... ok (4.3.2)
checking build system type... armv4l-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... armv4l-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a supported CPU... no (armv4l)
configure: error: Unsupported host architecture. Sorry
ts7500:/home/valgrind-3.8.1#
```

Comment: You might be best served by running the application for test purposes on an x86 class machine where you can use Valgrind. It sounds like the solution you're looking for is "how do I force this square peg into that round hole", which rarely works out the way you would like it to.

Comment: thank you mah. I could debug the some part on x86 platform but the code is also hardware specific code. It would be more precises if I could debug the code on that device. If it is not possible to surplus the problem, I ask what I could use as an alternative to valgrind that would work on armv4l

Comment: There are many memory debuggers found with a simple google search but I cannot recommend any through personal use on an Arm platform. I've written my own in the past (which I used on Arm) by using GCC flags to wrap malloc/free/realloc/calloc/strdup and it worked out well. I don't have anything to share but it wasn't terribly difficult since the compiler supported it. I've also (not specifically for Arm) done similar using library-provided malloc hooking, which also worked well (but the wrap method was easier to develop).

Comment: Instead of debugging the *release* executable as per Valgrind, there are various instrumenting libraries like **dlmalloc**, etc.  These compile with memory tracing code.  This is independent of CPU architecture and generally only requires ANSI C or Posix.  This mechanism have strength and weaknesses.  A strength is *it will work for you*.